# Gcd of a Numbers

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

What is the Sum of GCD of this:where G is `gcd` of two numbers

```
G(1,x)+G(2,x)+G(3,x)+..G(x,x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pillai's arithmetical function, [OEIS sequence A018804](https://oeis.org/A018804)

Comment: How i Can i find the `n` term

Comment: The OEIS page I linked to has several formulas, and programs in Maple, Mathematica, Pari and Haskell.